# WPF what happened to the dispatcher object on UI elements?

Tags: wpf

Many years ago I was easily able to invoke the dispatcher on any UIElement simply like this.

```
MyWPFTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke...
```

Either my intellisense isn't working or it's been moved....  because no Dispatcher property appears now.  Anybody know, how do I get addressibility to dispatcher from XAML element?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Windows.Threading;`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ...hmm, my intellisense is working for everything but seeing the Dispatcher property, even after adding the namespace above.  I'm using VS2013 SP 4, .NET 4.5...  I saw this back in VS2012, same issue, but never saw it in VS2010...  So I am not sure what's going on with this.

Comment: @JohnPeters I just tested on VS2012, it *could* be an issue in 2013 but I'd have to check tonight as I don't have 2013 at work.

Comment: OmegaMan nailed it, it's a bug that pops up in Visual Studio from time to time.  I think I saw this back in VS2010 even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the `Statement Completion` section for the language of the text editor is checked for `Auto list members`. I turn it on for all languages globally.

I show this on my blog article:

[Visual Studio Fix: Intellisense Not Popping Up or Not Working](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008)

Comment: It was set, but I've reset the values and will post back findings.

Comment: Thanks, your link helped me to solve this sporadic bug issue.

Comment: @JohnPeters Glad to help. Why do you still have this issue open? Is there another problem that has not been answered?

Answer (score 2):

As of .NET 4.5, it's still there (even in intellisense), so I'm guessing your Intellisense is currently busted.

A few things to note:

- You usually use the async version `BeginInvoke` in current WPF
- Having to marshal actions to the UI thread means you are probably doing it wrong. A proper binding setup will marshal your changes correctly with no extra effort.
- You don't need to use `Dispatcher` on a specific control, the one on your root UI element will suffice (ie, just `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`)

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminders, I'm very aware of your suggestions, but still just needed a quick dispatcher invoke on a test project I'm working on now.

Comment: @JohnPeters No worries, the comments were more for future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:  Intellisense was busted per suggestion from Omega man above, once I reset the settings in his post everything worked as it should.

Comment: I'll try @OmegaMan's suggestion, on resetting the config. settings and post back results.